# How to pass a parameter in the string in python using format

Tags: python, django, string.format

There as a url link which i have in settings.py file :

```
KAVENEGAR_URL = "https://api.kavenegar.com/v1/{key}/verify/lookup.json?receptor={phone}&token={otp}".format(key,phone,otp)
```

I want to use it in service.py file inside send_otp_sms method
I dont know how to pass key, phone, otp variables in it

```
from django.conf import settings

def send_otp_sms(key, phone, otp):
    kavenegar_url = settings.KAVENEGAR_URL.format(key, phone, otp)
    response = requests.post(kavenegar_url)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise APICallError
    return response
```

I used .format as you see in the codes but it pass error in settings.py which
Unresolved reference 'key'
Unresolved reference 'phone'
Unresolved reference 'otp'

Comment: You don't need to use `{}` after `format`, you are creating sets. Use them only inside the format string. Like this: `"b = {b}".format(b=value)`

Comment: the error still says `name 'key' and 'phone' and 'otp' are not defined`  in settings.py

Comment: Have you fixed the format to use `format(key=key, phone=phone, otp=otp)` like I said?

Comment: yes i changed settings.py to `format(key=key, phone=phone, otp=otp)` and the method in services.py to `settings.KAVENEGAR_URL.format(key, phone, otp)` but the file settings.py has this error : `name 'key' and 'phone' and 'otp' are not defined`

Comment: Remove the format entirely from the config and use the format string like I said in the `send_otp_sms` function

Comment: i changed settings.py to `KAVENEGAR_URL = "https://api.kavenegar.com/v1/{key}/verify/lookup.json?receptor={phone}&token={otp}"` and changed the function to :  `kavenegar_url = settings.KAVENEGAR_URL.format(key, phone, otp)` now the error in `KeyError: 'key' 
`from the function

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this that when i use parameters in the string like this :

`KAVENEGAR_URL = "https://api.kavenegar.com/v1/{key}/verify/lookup.json?receptor={phone}&token={otp}"`

I have to use .format like this :

`.format(key=key, phone=phone, otp=otp)`

and if i use empty braces like this :

`KAVENEGAR_URL = "https://api.kavenegar.com/v1/{}/verify/lookup.json?receptor={}&token={}"`

I have to use .format like this :

`.format(key, phone, otp)`

Answer (score -1):

Tente Isso:

```
from django.conf import settings

def send_otp_sms(key, phone, otp):
  kavenegar_url = f"https://api.kavenegar.com/v1/{key}/verify/lookup.json?receptor={phone}&token={otp}"
  response = requests.post(kavenegar_url)
  if response.status_code != 200:
    raise APICallError
  return response
```

Comment: No I dont want to use the url in the method